# Android JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, tesseract

I'm trying to run a Googles OCR Tesseract with my android project. I have already complied tesseract with android-ndk and am receiving this error after I try and run the android project.

My environment is as follows

- Android 5.1.1
- android-ndk-r10e for windows
- android-sdk-r22

For reference, I'm building from an example that is listed here [Example Link](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2015/05/15/create-an-ocr-android-app-with-cordova-and-tesseract)

Thanks in advance!

Here is a snippet of my logcat result:

```
  I/DEBUG   (  182): Revision: '0'
    I/DEBUG   (  182): ABI: 'arm'
    I/DEBUG   (  182): pid: 20291, tid: 20337, name: JavaBridge  >>> com.enterprisem
    obility.OCR <<<
    I/DEBUG   (  182): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    I/DEBUG   (  182): Abort message: 'art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERR
    OR IN APPLICATION: JNI GetMethodID called with pending exception 'java.lang.NoSu
    chFieldError' thrown in void com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI.native
    ClassInit():-2'
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     r0 00000000  r1 00004f71  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     r4 a0701db8  r5 00000006  r6 0000000b  r7 0000010c
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     r8 00000000  r9 b486f520  sl a1c0ac00  fp 00000001
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     ip 00004f71  sp a07006d8  lr b6e503c5  pc b6e72f6c  cpsr
    60070010
    I/DEBUG   (  182):
    I/DEBUG   (  182): backtrace:
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #00 pc 00039f6c  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #01 pc 000173c1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #02 pc 00017fd3  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #03 pc 00014795  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abor
    t+36)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #04 pc 00012f44  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #05 pc 00228cd7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abo
    rt()+170)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #06 pc 000a7371  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::
    ~LogMessage()+1360)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #07 pc 000b1b17  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(cha
    r const*, char const*)+1118)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #08 pc 000b2055  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(ch
    ar const*, char const*, ...)+68)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #09 pc 000b530f  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ScopedCheck:
    :ScopedCheck(_JNIEnv*, int, char const*)+1346)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #10 pc 000b7755  /system/lib/libart.so (art::CheckJNI::Ge
    tMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*)+36)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #11 pc 001332f7  /data/app/com.enterprisemobility.OCR-1/l
    ib/arm/libtess.so (Java_com_googlecode_tesseract_android_TessBaseAPI_nativeClass
    Init+46)
    I/DEBUG   (  182):     #12 pc 0000614d  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.ente
    rprisemobility.OCR-1@base.apk@classes.dex
    W/ActivityManager(  536):   Force finishing activity 1 com.enterprisemobility.OC
    R/.MainActivity
    I/DEBUG   (  182):
    I/DEBUG   (  182): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_07
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The *Abort message* is relatively clear: you call `GetFieldID(cls, fieldName)` for a field name that does not exist in the class you pass to this function, but you don't check for that error, and continue to call other JNI functions. Unfortunately, you cannot ignore such errors. You *must* call `ExceptionClear()` before calling `GetMethodID()` or *most* of the JNI functions.

You can use **addr2line** to find which specific call to `getMethodID()` crashed, and based on this, derive which call to `GetFieldID(cls, fieldName)` failed. But I would advise to add error checking to all your JNI calls, because tomorrow some other function may throw an exception.

Comment: So I've followed your suggestions and was able to track down the error. It appears its happening in the jini.h file in the android-ndk. Once I call ExceptionClear(), Ill have to rebuild my .so files correct?

Comment: Should this suffice ?     void ExceptionClear(JNIEnv *env)
    { functions->ExceptionClear(this); }

Comment: I assume that you rely later on the methodID which you failed to Get, so adding env->ExceptionClear() will probably not be enough. Any changes to the C++ code require rebuild of the .so file.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem,and it confuse me 2 days.Finally the reason is that I pass the wrong object type.For example,
the java code is

```
public OverlayLine(int mWidth,List<GeoPoint> mPoints);
```

and I register jni method as below:

```
gClass.mInitMethod = env->GetMethodID(gObject, "<init>", "(ILjava/lang/Object;)V");
```

and gets the error message as Errol encounter.And I fix the code

```
gClass.mInitMethod = env->GetMethodID(gObject, "<init>", "(ILjava/util/List;)V");
```

and the error gone.That you should pass the precise object type rather than 'Ljava/lang/Object;'.

Comment: When this happens, it breaks the handshaking so that the NEXT GetMethodID/GetFieldID causes the system to crash.  Even if THAT call's syntax is OK. So you need to look one GetMethodID/GetFieldID back from where it actually stops.  ...It is helpful to reduplicate the same statement three times when debugging code. Good statements don't hurt to be re-called, whereas when it crashes between the second & third invocations, you'll know that it's actually the first invocation of a bad statement that bolluxed the system up. ...note compiler perfectly fine with using Ljava/lang/Object; , RUN time bug.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the JNI mappings were incorrectly defined in your C++ code.  JNI has very strict contracts about type mappings with Java.  For example,
before calling a Java object's method from JNI, we need its signature. So the method:

`long myMethod (int n, String s, int[] arr);`

is seen from JNI with the signature:

`(ILJAVA/LANG/STRING;[I])J`

You can read a very comprehensive overview of these rules here:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0286.html

Answer (score 0):

you should use ndk-stack tool in android NDK to find out the crashed position. see the link about [ndk stack](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html).

```
adb logcat > /tmp/foo.txt

$NDK/ndk-stack -sym $PROJECT_PATH/obj/local/armeabi -dump foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the similar problem when calling GetMethodID:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[1,tid=15092,Runnable,Thread*=0x791c1b8000,peer=0x7278ab58,"main"] using JNI after critical get
...   in call to GetMethodID
```

A few calls before GetMethodID im use

```
inBufP = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical(jIn, NULL);
```

**Solution :**
I can fix native crash by change **GetPrimitiveArray** to **GetByteArrayElements**

```
jboolean isCopy;
inBufP = env->GetByteArrayElements(jIn, &isCopy);
```