# Runtime JNI android error. What could be causing this

Tags: android

A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: thread Thread[1,tid=23146,Runnable,Thread*=0xb1059000,peer=0x7307b978,"main"] using JNI after critical get
A/zygote: java_vm_ext.cc:534]     in call to DeleteGlobalRef

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34891686/android-jni-detected-error-in-application-jni-getmethodid-called-with-pending-e

Comment: @AdeelAhmed I think is a totally different error.Maybe you can explain the relationship of what you have directed me to with what you I have

Comment: Sorted it out. I found that reuse of variables stored in R. Java does not happen as long as it has an object which has not been garbaged out. I simply ensured every item only used any variable once and left the system to clean up.